# Flickr api title

Tags: php, html, xml, api, flickr

Hello everyone I am trying to make a gallery on my website and I am pulling the images/sets from flickr. I am able to load all the sets with this bit of code:

```
$flickr = simplexml_load_file('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key='.$api.'&user_id='.$user_id.'');
foreach($flickr->photosets->photoset as $ps) {
      echo '<img src="http://farm'.$ps['farm'].'.staticflickr.com/'.$ps['server'].'/'.$ps['primary'].'_'.$ps['secret'].'_q.jpg"><br />';
}
```

With this it will return a list of all the set's main images. However I also would like to add the title above it but the XML output of the title is in `$flickr->photosets->photoset->title` making it hard for me to get the title above every picture. Is there a easy way to get the title inside the `foreach` loop for the images but that the title also aligns correctly with the image?

the xml flickr outputs looks like:

```
<photosets page="1" pages="1" perpage="30" total="2" cancreate="1">
  <photoset id="72157626216528324" primary="5504567858" secret="017804c585" server="5174" farm="6" photos="22" videos="0" count_views="137" count_comments="0" can_comment="1" date_create="1299514498" date_update="1300335009">
    <title>Avis Blanche</title>
    <description>My Grandma's Recipe File.</description>
  </photoset>
</photosets>
```

Comment: Looks like you want `$ps['title']`, but your problem is with the HTML/CSS, not with Flickr. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes but the title isn't in $flickr->photosets->photoset it is in $flickr->photosets->photoset->title let me edit my post to clarify it :)

Comment: So you should be able to do `$ps->title`, shouldn't you?

Comment: How should it look once it is done? Right now you have a list of images that are inline-objects, each with a `<br/>` at the end. What do you want to produce? Where should the headings go?

Comment: Thanks simbabque the $ps->title was the answer I was looking for! I guess im not that good at explaining problems haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's with the given XML, you can obtain it inside of the `foreach` loop with `$ps->title`.

Comment: Thanks Lumbendil this was indeed the answer I was looking for! Worked like a charm!